# Error while parsing volley response in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin programming, I am trying to get JSONObject from my string response but i am not able to do so.

Here is my code:

```
fun getPosts() {

        val url = BASE_URL + GET_POST + "?UserID=${globalUserProfile?.userID}&PostOwnerID=${globalUserProfile?.userID}"

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)

        val stringRequest = object: StringRequest(Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->

            Log.d("API RESPONSE: ", "Response in string: " + response)

            val stringResponse = response.toString()
            val jsonResponse = JSONObject(stringResponse)

        }, Response.ErrorListener {

            Toast.makeText(activity, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }) {

            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {

                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()

                val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = activity!!.getSharedPreferences(GET_SHARED_PREFERENCES, SHARED_PREFERENCES_PRIVATE_MODE)
                val tokenFromPreferences = sharedPref.getString(SHARED_PREFERENCES_TOKEN, "Default Token")

                headers["Verifytoken"] = tokenFromPreferences ?: "Default Token"

                return headers

            }

        }

        queue.add(stringRequest)

    }
```

Here's the response in string:

```
<pre>Array
    (
        [week1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [PostID] => 4
                        [Title] => CoD
                        [Description] => dummy caption
                        [Tags] => dummy name
                        [UserID] => 1
                        [PostVideo] => uploads/post/videos/9248674463720200302113734.mp4
                        [PostImage] => 
                        [SortOrder] => 0
                        [Hide] => 0
                        [IsActive] => 1
                        [CreatedAt] => 1583951969
                        [UpdatedAt] => 1583148877
                        [CreatedBy] => 0
                        [UpdatedBy] => 0
                        [FullName] => 
                        [UserImage] => uploads/images/560345183620200226014232.png
                        [LikesCount] => 0
                        [IsLiked] => 0
                        [ReadCount] => 0
                    )

            )

        [week2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [PostID] => 3
                        [Title] => CoD
                        [Description] => dummy caption
                        [Tags] => dummy name
                        [UserID] => 1
                        [PostVideo] => uploads/post/videos/4755111040320200302113134.mp4
                        [PostImage] => 
                        [SortOrder] => 0
                        [Hide] => 0
                        [IsActive] => 1
                        [CreatedAt] => 1583148871
                        [UpdatedAt] => 1583148871
                        [CreatedBy] => 0
                        [UpdatedBy] => 0
                        [FullName] => 
                        [UserImage] => uploads/images/560345183620200226014232.png
                        [LikesCount] => 2
                        [IsLiked] => 0
                        [ReadCount] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [PostID] => 9
                        [Title] => CoD
                        [Description] => asd
                        [Tags] => xzc
                        [UserID] => 1
                        [PostVideo] => 
                        [PostImage] => 
                        [SortOrder] => 0
                        [Hide] => 0
                        [IsActive] => 1
                        [CreatedAt] => 1583164944
                        [UpdatedAt] => 1583164944
                        [CreatedBy] => 0
                        [UpdatedBy] => 0
                        [FullName] => 
                        [UserImage] => uploads/images/560345183620200226014232.png
                        [LikesCount] => 0
                        [IsLiked] => 0
                        [ReadCount] => 0
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [PostID] => 5
                        [Title] => CoD
                        [Description] => dummy caption
                        [Tags] => dummy name
                        [UserID] => 1
                        [PostVideo] => uploads/post/videos/687237077420200302113834.mp4
                        [PostImage] => 
                        [SortOrder] => 0
                        [Hide] => 0
                        [IsActive] => 1
                        [CreatedAt] => 1583148878
                        [UpdatedAt] => 1583148878
                        [CreatedBy] => 0
                        [UpdatedBy] => 0
                        [FullName] => 
                        [UserImage] => uploads/images/560345183620200226014232.png
                        [LikesCount] => 0
                        [IsLiked] => 0
                        [ReadCount] => 0
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [PostID] => 2
                        [Title] => 
                        [Description] => hamza update
                        [Tags] => 
                        [UserID] => 1
                        [PostVideo] => uploads/post/videos/3259382345320200302111833.mp4
                        [PostImage] => 
                        [SortOrder] => 0
                        [Hide] => 0
                        [IsActive] => 1
                        [CreatedAt] => 1583148798
                        [Upd
```

The error occurred on "val jsonResponse = JSONObject(stringResponse)" line
I tried putting JSONArray but again gets the same error

Here's the error:

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

2020-03-15 15:02:58.793 7721-7721/com.example.GameX E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.GameX, PID: 7721
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:502)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value Array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
        at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:168)
        at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:181)
        at com.example.GameX.homeScreenFragment$getPosts$stringRequest$2.onResponse(homeScreenFragment.kt:65)
        at com.example.GameX.homeScreenFragment$getPosts$stringRequest$2.onResponse(homeScreenFragment.kt:60)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Comment: But your response is not JSON at all. How is it supposed to parsed?

Comment: I have other Volley requests also, and i am using exact this behaviour to parse them, they all are working fine, this one is getting error. :-(

Comment: It's because this API is not returning data in JSON format. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: Yes, You were right. The Api response was just simple plain text printed Array. It is now solved. Thanks a lot. :-)